# SQL Command return user greater than threshold value

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I have a project where I want to return a user who appears more than a threshold value in a column. I type command:

`Select User from Table`

It displays all the users in the table. However, I just want to get the user who appears in the column more than a threshold value, for example 5. If a user in the column appears more than 5, it should only return the user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do a `GROUP BY`. Use `HAVING` to return only users appearing more than 5 times.

```
select user from table
group by user
having count(*) > 5
```

Comment: You can count the user only instead of all * though the result will be same but why not to follow better approach.

Comment: @Suraz, why is that a better approach?

Comment: I am not certain but may be he is indicating this : `COUNT(*) vs COUNT(col)`. But I am not sure if it matters in MySQL.

Comment: @1000111, yes, probably. But why should that be "a better approach" here?

Comment: @jarlh, use both count(*) and count(id) in huge data then you get the difference. count(*) hits the performance very badly. Just suggestion you can ignore also.

Comment: @Suraz, do you mean MySQL is slower doing `count(*)` than `count(user)`? (When GROUP BY.)

Comment: I don't know @jarlh . I am not even advocating his point. I am just not certain about this in MySQL. I would do the same what you did.

Comment: @1000111 . . . `COUNT(*)` usually optimizes better than using a specific column.  If `user` were indexed, then it probably would not make a difference.

Comment: Thanks @GordonLinoff. Performance may worsen while using `Count(col)` if `col` is not indexed and allows `null`. Can I infer that?